# discord.js bot replies to itself

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I am currently coding my first discord bot, it can already play YouTube music.

```javascript
if (message.content.includes("Good Job") || 
    message.content.includes("good job")) {
    message.channel.sendMessage("Good Job everyone :smirk:");
}
```

As you see, if someone types "good job" (this is just an example) then the bot will reply with "good job everyone :smirk:), but then the spam will begin: the bot reads his own message and replies to it.

How can I prevent the bot from answering itself?

Comment: check to see who sent the message? If the bot sent the message dont reply.

Comment: check user or userID...

Comment: Always convert the message to lowercase/uppercase first before checking instead of checking both versions of the message in your *if* statement. Just a tip for you!

Comment: @zGeek How do i convert messages in if (message.content = "xx") {} tolowercase ?

Comment: @gitgudgithub Make a variable like this:
`var msg = message.content.toLowerCase();`
Then use the *msg* variable for your string matches.

Answer (score 29):

Use this in the on message event:

```
if (message.author.bot) return;
```

for more info:
https://anidiotsguide.gitbooks.io/discord-js-bot-guide/coding-guides/a-basic-command-handler.html

Comment: I also just want to mention this: message received handler is called whenever the bot 'sees' a new message. (And that message includes the message from the bot itself!) The same applies to your account too! Try pinging @everyone in your own server, and you will see the yellow highlight bar pops-up even though the message from yourself.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that! I usually have a block of code (if the sender is NOT the bot) wrapping around all the code inside the message event, and everything goes inside of it, that needs to be filtered.

Comment: if(message.author.username === client.user.username) {return;} would be better so that you can also answer to a bot.

Answer (score 7):

The reason why your bot replies to yourself is because where you put:

```
if (message.content.includes("Good Job") || 
    message.content.includes("good job"))
```

It is basically checking the chat if a piece of text **includes** the words "Good Job" or "good job". As your bot sends:

```js
message.channel.sendMessage("Good Job everyone :smirk:");
```

as an answer, it creates a loop because that message **includes the words** *"Good Job"*, basically running the code again and again and again.

Of course, the easiest way of fixing this is for you to change the answer it gives to not include the words *Good Job*, but there is better solution to make sure it doesn't happen for all of the commands you might make.

As @Jörmungandr said, under the message event include:

```js
if (message.author.bot) return;
```

to make sure it doesn't happen. It essentially checks if the author of the message is a bot and if it is, it ignores it.

[discord.js](/questions/tagged/discord.js)

Answer (score 6):

```js
// In message event
if(message.author.id === client.user.id) return;

// I would recommend a variable like this for splits on words
// const args = message.content.trim().split(/\s+/g); 
// You could also .slice() off a prefix if you have one

if(/good job/i.test(message.content)) {
  message.channel.send('Good job everyone :smirk:'); // sendMessage is deprecated, use send instead
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply just check if the user sending the message is a bot. For example:

```
if (!msg.author.bot) {
    <Your code to execute if the user is not a bot.>
}
```

Hope this was helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may use this code which avoids doing anything if the author is a bot:

```js
if(message.author.bot) return;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a lot of ways to solve this.

## 1: Stopping the Bot from Responding to ANY bot.

Right under your message callback (the `client.once('message')`), you can just add:

```js
if (message.author.bot) return;
```

## 2: Stopping the Bot from Responding to itself

Once again, right under your message callback, you just add:

```js
if (message.author.id == client.user.id) return;
```

Please note the `client` that I am referring to is your bot's client, created when you type

```js
const client = new Discord.Client()
```

...or whatever your client is. It's basically the thing that you login to (ex: `client.login(yourtokenhere)`)

Most tutorials will call this `Client`, `client`, or maybe even `bot`. The discord.js guide will call it a `Client`.