# Discord Bot replying to itself, doesn't recognize message.author.bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.io

so I have a bot that I'm trying to make respond to "Dan" with "We love Dan!" for a server I'm in:

```
var Discord = require('discord.io');
var logger = require('winston');
var auth = require('./auth.json');
// Configure logger settings
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, {
    colorize: true
});
logger.level = 'debug';
// Initialize Discord Bot
var mybot = new Discord.Client({
    token: auth.token,
    autorun: true
});
mybot.on('ready', function (evt) {
    logger.info('Connected');
    logger.info('Logged in as: ');
    logger.info(mybot.username + ' - (' + mybot.id + ')');
});
mybot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.includes("Dan")) {
            mybot.sendMessage({
                to: channelID,
                message: 'We love Dan!',
            });
     }
});
```

I've looked up how to get a bot to not respond to itself, and many suggested that line of code

```
if (message.author.bot) return;
```

but when I put that in, I'm getting this error in the command prompt:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'bot' of undefined

It seems from threads like [discord.js bot replies to itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46157012/discord-js-bot-replies-to-itself) that the solution works for people, but it's not for me.

What am I doing differently?

Thanks!

Comment: The thread you linked to for a possible solution is for a different discord JS library than you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that `message.author` is `undefined`, therefore `bot` is not a valid property. You are attempting to use a solution from another discord library.

Instead, try checking if the user or user ID matches the bot's and then return.

Comment: "if (message.userID === mybot.userID) return;" doesn't return an error but the bot also doesn't reply to anyone

Comment: P.S. I'm gonna try rebuilding the bot in discord.js since that'll be less of a headache when I add more code in the future, but I suppose I'm still curious what I'd have to do to make it work as it stands (and other people viewing this thread in the future might be too)

Comment: This answer is direct to the question.  `message.author` is the undefined element. If you keep building with `discord.io` proly want to console.log out the `message` var and see what it's storing in there...

Answer (score 1):

Hmmmmm....  At first glance looks like a scoping issue.  Not sure what exactly you are building with, you may want to read [MCV](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Need to clean out the little bot I built and post it on github, doing that tomorrow I'll post it then.  Was experimenting with short term memory array.  But with a quick look and a test got this working:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
...
client.on("message", async message => {
  if (message.content.includes("Dan")){
    // right that is needed to kill the loop ->
    if(message.author.bot) return; 
    return message.reply("We love you Dan!");
    // could also use -> message.channel.send("We love you Dan!")
  } 
}
```

`client` in my case is `bot` in yours I believe and it will reply on the async or return so you will just need to call the in-built prototype method that exists as part of method.  There are a bunch of others as well in the API Docs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I added the full code to the post if that info helps.

Comment: After a quick look I'd say switch to `discord.js`.  Community echos make it sound like io is not so well supported anymore.  js is rad and works great right outa the gate... stole this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/eslachance/3349734a98d30011bb202f47342601d3) and built a thing.  Try it out, ES6 also, which is the new javascript and what you should be writing in...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, before this I honestly didn't know there was a difference between discord.io and discord.js (this is my first bot and I followed some online tutorial) but discord.js is SO MUCH easier. Thank you!

Comment: Yup, no worry, cleaned up the [repo](https://github.com/ed42311/discord-bot) if you want to check it out.  It's an expansion on that gist, was in the middle of building a python script to build responses from user input only, but scrapped it...  fun stuff.